# Formcontrol error while getting dynamic name?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting typeError here`<p  *ngIf="formValue.controls['{{obj.name}}'].invalid` but when I hard code  like this `*ngIf="formValue.controls['uname'].invalid` it works fine.

what is the problem here?

```
<span *ngFor="let obj of toolData">
    <span [ngSwitch]="obj.type">
        <span *ngSwitchCase="'text'">
            <label for="{{obj.name}}">{{obj.label}}</label>
            <input type="text" id="{{obj.name}}" name="{{obj.name}}" formControlName="{{obj.name}}" value="{{obj.value}}" required="{{obj.required}}" />
             <p *ngIf="formValue.controls['{{obj.name}}'].invalid && formValue.controls['{{obj.name}}'].touched" class="text-danger">Value required</p>
        </span>
     </span>
</span>
```

ToolData

```
toolData=[
    {"type":"text","name":"uname","label":"User Name","value":"user name","required":true},
    {"type":"number","name":"pval","label":"P val","value":"3","min":0,"max":100,"required":true},
]
```

Comment: You don't need string interpolation in a `*ngIf` expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngIf` evaluates the expression written inside that. You dont have to use string interpolation there. Use expression as below.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/v96yz5m7/) jsfiddle will show a sample implementation.

It should be

```
*ngIf="formValue.controls[obj.name].invalid && formValue.controls[obj.name].touched"
```

So your template will be.

```
<span *ngFor="let obj of toolData">
    <span [ngSwitch]="obj.type">
        <span *ngSwitchCase="'text'">
            <label for="{{obj.name}}">{{obj.label}}</label>
            <input type="text" id="{{obj.name}}" name="{{obj.name}}" formControlName="{{obj.name}}" value="{{obj.value}}" required="{{obj.required}}" />
             <p *ngIf="formValue.controls[obj.name].invalid && formValue.controls[obj.name].touched" class="text-danger">Value required</p>
        </span>
     </span>
</span>
```